# how to use ChangeListener for JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

```
private String[]fontsizelist = {"10","15","20"};
private SpinnerListModel spinmodel = new SpinnerListModel(fontsizelist);
private JSpinner fontsizeitem= new JSpinner(spinmodel);
//Constructor

some codes


         fontsizeitem.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){

        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
            for(int i=0;i<fontsizelist.length;i++){
                fontsizeitem [i]=new JSpinner(fontsizelist[i]);<-shows error 
            }
        }
    });
```

This code shows me an error message

array required, but JSpinner found

I know what is the problem but I have no idea how should I fix.

I am using a string array because an integer array did not work with

SpinnerNumberModel and SpinnerListModel.

The font size should be changed automatically when the state of JSpinner is

changed. How should I do in my case?

Comment: Get the current value from the `JSpinner` using `JSpinner#getValue`, which will be a `String`, so you'll need convert it to an `Integer`

Comment: `SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(10, 10, 20, 5);` would also give you a similar result as your `fontsizelist`

Comment: `fontsizeitem [i]=new JSpinner(fontsizelist[i]);` What is it you are trying to achieve in that code line.. it makes no sense to me. 1) The spinner has already been instantiated, why create it again? 2) The first part is indeed implying that `fontsizeitem` is an array. It was not declared as one. 3) It seems to be trying to create an array of spinners each with a single item of the original spinner. A spinner with a single item makes no sense, and an array of them makes even less sense.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I thought it would work the same as JMenuItem. I just wanted get items  from array and put that into JSpinner

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for comments. I will try both your and the answer's suggestions

Comment: *"I thought it would work the same as JMenuItem."* I can't see how any of that would work with a `JMenuItem` either, but ..whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should start with [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

A `SpinnerNumberModel` setup right (min of `10`, max of `20` and a step of `5`) would give you the same result as your `fontsizelist`

The basic idea is, the `JSpinner` will notify your `ChangeListener` when the value is changed, from that, you need to get a reference of the `JSpinner` and get it's current value, for example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(10, 10, 20, 5);
            JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
            add(spinner);

            spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    JSpinner spinner = (JSpinner) e.getSource();
                    int value = (int)spinner.getValue();
                    System.out.println("Value is " + value);
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `int value = (int)spinner.getValue();` to avoid the cast, I'd typically call `model.getNumber().intValue()` ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson That's a fair comment, I assumed the OP might not have a reference to the model and in the case of the example, I can "almost" justify the blind cast :P

Comment: *"I assumed the OP might not have a reference to the model.."* I regularly use spinners, but never keep a reference to the component, only the model. I have a pathological dislike of casting. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Guess my experience is the other way round, but in this case, you're right, I could have attached the listener to model, but I'd still have to cast the source, also, I'm no fan of casting either 

Comment: *"I could have attached the listener to model"* Huh.. I just learned something new. I didn't realise I could add the listener direct to the model (though it seems logical, ..now you mention it!). Currently I add the listener to the spinner component before it goes out of scope. :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you! I did not just copy and paste your code but your advice were really helpful! Now it works! Thank you!

Comment: worked great! If your are use Netbeans to build the GUI, just edit the Spinner creation adding the part of spinner.addChangeListener( ... using the menu "Code" / "Post Creation code" in the GUI Menu.